# inline keyword causes linker error 2019 in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, inline

I've been on a hiatus from using MSVC and vaguely remember having no problems inlining class member functions.  However, when I use the inline keyword as such:

```
//In header file
class A {
    public:
        inline void funcA(void);
};

//In cpp file
void A::funcA(void) {

}
```

I get a LNK2019, unresolved symbol (even though the function matches exactly what the error says is missing).  I've tried marking both the header and definition as inline, and the same thing happens.  I also removed the inline keyword after trying to build, and the error remains until I clean the solution, after which everything builds fine sans-inline.  Nobody seems to have the same issue when I Google the problem, suggesting I'm missing some obvious thing... but what is it?

Comment: Is funcA used in another translation unit than the one it is defined in? If so, that is what is causing the error, because the compiler needs to know the definition in order to replace calls with the functions body. You need one, identical, definition in each translation unit, therefore it should probably be placed in the header, not the cpp file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline functions should be defined in the header always. It does not have to be inside the class definition, but it should be in the header. If you didn't put it in the header, other modules including the .h file would not be able to see the definition and inline it....

For your information, recent versions of Visual C++ have Link Time Code Generation, that allows the compiler to inline functions in other modules (= cpp file), even if the to be inlined functions are defined in other .cpp files. But this is a proprietary extension, and is done without regard for the `inline` keyword. The portable way is to use `inline` and put it in the header.

Comment: For future reference, what if I have a really long public function that I want to inline because it's only used once?  Should I define it in the header, or just not inline it at all?

Comment: If it is used outside the class that defines it, it has to be in the header.

Comment: @NmdMystery You can put it after the class declaration, though, so people can see the class without large methods in the way. If all the code you showed above was in the header, you'd be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you make your inline member public or protected you should put the definition in the header. An exemption is a private inline (without any friend access), if it is used in the source, only. (A clean might be necessary to fix the precompiled header)